# unable to connect to sql server aspnetdb.mdf

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am new to asp.net and just started to work. I am facing the below issue and tried a whole day doing lot research and couldn't find a solution. Can anyone help me solve this.

> Unable to open the physical file
>   "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Project\MIS\MIS\MIS\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf".
>   Operating system error 2: "2(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105)".
>       Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Project\MIS\MIS\MIS\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf'
>   as database 'Adventure'.

Connection String:

```
<add name="ConnectionString"
 connectionString="data source=ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Adventure;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I am running my webapplication in my local machine and not on any servers.

Comment: Did you look at the EXACT path listed in the error message to ensure that the file is EXACTLY in that location?  Also, verify that the user account running Visual Studio (your login account unless set to run as admin) has access to the file.

Comment: @Eric J. - I remove this part `AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf` in connectionstring and now it's not connecting to my sql server. It says `Cannot open database "Adventure" requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user 'Admin-PC\Admin'.`

Comment: Do you know the user name and password for the mdf?  Because the one you are using isnt it.

Comment: You have SQLExpress installed on your machine judging by your connection string, so why not just put the database in your server instead of having it in the data directory of your application? See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ Attaching your DB on the fly can be a major pita, as sometimes you have to detach it before an updated db can be reattached, and sometimes theres a timer set on the automated detachment, i.e. don't do it! :D

Comment: Try <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=Adventure;integrated security=false;User ID=webserver;Password=webserver" /> for this you must create a user in the database with username webserver and password webserver and give them database role membership of reader, writer and owner - NOT ownership scheme stuff! ... Manually attach the db to your sql express instance, then select security then right click on user and add new user.

Answer (score 0):

> **Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Project\MIS\MIS\MIS\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf". Operating system error 2: "2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)".
>   Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Project\MIS\MIS\MIS\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\MusicalInstrumentalStore.UI\App_Data\aspnetdb.mdf' as database 'Adventure'.**

Right Click to Your `aspnetdb.mdf` go to properties > then Security Tab
and then give full rights to   your `user account`
if you did not found you user account then click add button and add your `user account` and give full rights to your 'user account'

[image]